# RobotFramework not recognizing "Alert Should Be Present" for alert window

Tags: alert, robotframework

My site has an alert window, that needs to be closed before continuing, that RF is not recognizing and closing. Pretty clear on the Key Word usage

```
Alert Should Be Present  my text
```

Per RF:

> Verifies an alert is present and dismisses it.
>
> If text is a non-empty string, then it is also verified that the
>   message of the alert equals to text.
>
> Will fail if no alert is present. Note that when running tests with
>   selenium, the alerts will not be visible in the browser. Nevertheless,
>   following keywords will fail unless the alert is dismissed by this
>   keyword or by Get Alert Message. (which I tried to utilize as well).

Comment: are you sure this is an alert and not a pop-windows where you need to confirm or cancel? Alerts have only one button (are you sure?) and confirm contains multiple choices (yes, no, cancel). If this is a confirm pop-up, you should try the "confirm action" keyword (http://robotframework-seleniumlibrary.googlecode.com/hg/doc/SeleniumLibrary.html?r=2.8#Confirm%20Action)

Comment: have you tried putting in a short sleep prior to this line? Maybe the test is running too fast for the site and you're not giving the alert a chance to pop up. A short sleep isn't usually the right final solution, but it's useful while debugging your test.

Answer (score -2):

Use below Code to Confirm your action

```
| | ${msg} | Confirm Action
```